# Py-Spark equivalent of Pandas.dataframe.shift() method

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Following is my dataframe:

```
Name    Len
Tom     3
Tommy   5
Rock    4
Rocky   5
```

I need following output dataframe:

```
Name    Len     New_Name    New_Len
Tom     3       Tommy       5
Tommy   5       Rock        4
Rock    4       Rocky       5
Rocky   5       ...         ...
```

With Pandas I can achieve this using

```py
df['new_name'] = df['name'].shift(-1)
df['new_len'] = df['len'].shift(-1)
```

Can I get any suggestions on how to achieve the same in PySpark? Is there any equivalent of `pandas.dataframe.shift()` method in PySpark?